# How can I see a list of the variables in a CSV column?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with over 5,000,000 rows of data that looks like this (except that it is in Farsi):

```
Contract Code,Contract Type,State,City,Property Type,Region,Usage Type,Area,Percentage,Price,Price per m2,Age,Frame Type,Contract Date,Postal Code
765720,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,96,100,570000,5937.5,36,Metal,13890107,5169614658
766134,Mobayee,East Azar,Qeshm,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1070000,7404.84,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766140,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1050000,7266.44,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766146,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,700000,4844.29,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766147,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1625000,11245.67,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
770822,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,50,500000,1730.1,5,Concrete,13890114,5166884645
```

I would like to have a code to list the variables in a specific column.
For example, I'd like it to return `{Kish, Qeshm, Tabriz}` for the `'city'` column.

Comment: Note that `{'Kish', 'Qeshm', 'Tabriz'}` is a **`set`** not a `list` which would be `['Kish', 'Qeshm', 'Tabriz']`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first to import the csv module into your python file and read over each row in the file and save it in a list, so it'll be like

```
import csv

cities = []
with open("yourfile.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)  //This will save the values in the very top of the csv file as header so it will skip a line
    for row in reader:
        city = row["City"]
        cities.append(city)
```

this will give you a list of `cities=[Kish, Qesh, Tabriz, ....]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I please have an example of it using pandas as well? I'm a beginner as you can tell and I'm trying to learn on the job.

Comment: @صبااسماعیلی: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to remove duplicates as well, which you can have by simply cast the finished list to `set`. Here's how to do it with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
cities = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', usecols=['City'])['City']

# just cast to list if you want a plain list instead of a DataFrame
cities_list = list(cities)

# use set to remove the duplicates
unique_cities = set(cities)
```

In case you have need to preserve ordering, you might use an [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) with just keys.

Also, in case you're short on memory trying to read 5M rows in one go, you can read them in chuncks:

```
import pandas as pd
cities_chunks_list = [chunck['City'] for chunck in pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', usecols=['City'], chunksize = 1000)]

#let's flatten the list
cities_list = [city for cities_chunk in cities_chunks_list for city in cities_chunk]
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: *All* dictionaries have been ordered since Python 3.7.

Comment: You are correct but there's plenty of people around who still use 3.6 or older versions.